# Python3 Json Dictionary output price print max with 2 decimal place

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I managed final out put from a json dictionary (Price of an item)

from the output price list , I want to find  the max number not grater then 1.90 with 2 decimal place

in the list we have 45.86834862385321  but my final output must print as  1.24

```
resp2json = rr.json()
a = (resp2json['data']['pencil'])

for b in a:
    final_data = b ['blue'] ['rate']
    print (final_data)
```

OUTPUT

```
1.2157339821573399
1.2413108242303872
1.2157339821573399
45.86834862385321
1.2165314401622718
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this code will return the output with 2 decimal place.

```py
resp2json = rr.json()
a = (resp2json['data']['pencil'])

for b in a:
    final_data = b ['blue'] ['rate']
    print (f'{final_data:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
data=[
1.2157339821573399,
1.2413108242303872,
1.2157339821573399,
45.86834862385321,
1.2165314401622718,
]
temp = 0 
for row in data:
    if temp < row < 1.9:
        temp = row
print(round(float(temp),2))
```

in your case code should be something like this:

```
resp2json = rr.json()
data = (resp2json['data']['pencil'])
temp = 0
for row in data:
    if temp < float(row['blue']['rate']) < 1.9:
        temp = float(row['blue']['rate'])
print(temp)
```

temp < row < 1.9 this is the logic you mentioned in your question

Comment: without round the answer is fine 

but when i use print(round(temp,2))

TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method

Comment: probably your data is str you can add `float` like this: `print(round(float(temp),2))`   @user12209531 i updated it on answer too

Comment: Thank you , its working as I wanted

Comment: its not working properly 

`
1.2150668286755772 
1.2135922330097086
1.2157339821573399
1.2534818941504178
1.2176063303659743
1.2172854534388313
1.2166504381694254
1.217720932924359
1.2157339821573399
1.2150668286755772
`
output is printing as 1.22 not 1.25  

1.25 is the max number

Comment: `1.2150668286755772 1.2135922330097086 1.2157339821573399 1.2534818941504178 1.2176063303659743 1.2172854534388313 1.2166504381694254 1.217720932924359 1.2157339821573399 1.2150668286755772` this is not a valid data you should split them with , and put it in an array or if this your data then you need to change the code `for row in data.split(" "):`

Comment: its the “rate”  fetch from json dictionary and I get the final data as shown in the question , so before comparing the max value I need to format the data  and put it into a list right ?

Comment: no you dont need that , you said that the value is `b['blue'] ['rate']` this one right, so all you need to do is chance row to this, I updated my Answer please check again , take the code below and try it. @user12209531

Comment: I could not fix the error this time by adding float .

    if temp < row['blue']['rate'] < 1.90:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str

Comment: convert it to `float` then? `if temp < float(row['blue']['rate']) < 1.90`

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float'

Comment: updated the answer!!